# VichUploader: reupload image on entity update

Tags: php, symfony, vichuploaderbundle

I have entity `Asset` with field image

```
 /**
  * @ORM\Table(name="asset")
  * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\AssetRepository")
  * @Vich\Uploadable
  */
 class Asset
 {

     /**
      * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
      */
     private $name;

     /**
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="assets")
      * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
      */
     private $category;

     /**
      * @ORM\Column(name="image", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
      */
     private $image;

     /**
      * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="assets", fileNameProperty="image")
      * @var File
      */
     protected $imageFile;
```

I am using VichUploader to upload images to S3 bucket. I created custom namer to create file name. During upload entity is uploaded to folder with category name and is named with entity name

```
public function name($obj, PropertyMapping $mapping)
{
    $category = $obj->getCategory()->getName();
    $name = $obj->getName();
    $file = $mapping->getFile($obj);

    if ($extension = $this->getExtension($file)) {
        $name = sprintf('%s.%s', $name, $extension);
    }

    return $category.'/'.$name;
}
```

These my upload configurations

```
oneup_flysystem:
adapters:
    assets_adapter:
        awss3v3:
            client: app.assets.s3
            bucket: '%assets_bucket%'
            prefix: assets

filesystems:
    assets_fs:
        adapter:    assets_adapter
        mount:      assets_fs

vich_uploader:
     db_driver: orm
     storage:   flysystem

mappings:
    assets:
        delete_on_remove: true
        delete_on_update: true
        uri_prefix:       'https://s3-%assets_region%.amazonaws.com/%assets_bucket%/'
        upload_destination: assets_fs
        namer: app.asset_namer
```

I have following situation: user changes category of Asset. How file can be re-uploaded to new category folder and update name?

**UPDATE**

I am using [EasyAdminBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/index.html). Which handles create and edit entities. So I didn't create FormType and Controller for Asset entity. Here are configs:

```
easy_admin:
  entities:
   Asset:
    class: AppBundle\Entity\Asset
    label: 'Assets'
    form:
      fields:
        - name
        - {property: 'category', type: entity, type_options: {expanded: false, multiple: false, class: 'AppBundle:Category', required: true}}
        - {property: 'imageFile', type: 'vich_image' }
```

Comment: Please show the update Controller and FormType object code, since that is where the model is manipulated. On that note; I would add a condition for when the category name changes, to recreate the existing File object from `getImageFile` with a new `File` object and call `setImageFile()` with the new `File` object. This would force the VichUploader update process.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to update the `Asset::setCategory` method logic, to create a new File object when the category name is changed, and pass it to `Asset::setImageFile` to cause VichUploader to run the update process.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="asset")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\AssetRepository")
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class Asset
{
     //...

     public function setCategory(Category $category)  
     {
         if ($this->imageFile && $this->category->getName() !== $category->getName()) {
             $this->setImageFile(new UploadedFile(
                 $this->imageFile->getRealPath(),  //physical path to image file
                 $this->image, //current image name
                 null, 
                 null, 
                 null, 
                 true
             ));
         }
         $this->category = $category;

         return $this;
     }

}
```

One issue is that by default VichUploader does not populate the entity imageFile property.

To ensure `Asset::$imageFile` is available, without needing to interact with the `vich_uploader.storage` service, you will need to add `inject_on_load: true` to your `vich_uploader.mappings` settings. This will add a listener to the entity to automatically populate the imageFile property with a `File` object.

```
#app/config/config.yml

#...

vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm
    storage: flysystem
    mappings:
        assets:
            delete_on_remove: true
            delete_on_update: true
            uri_prefix: 'https://s3-%assets_region%.amazonaws.com/%assets_bucket%/'
            upload_destination: assets_fs
            namer: app.asset_namer
            inject_on_load: true
```

---

The prefered method would be to add the logic to your [controller edit action](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/complex-dynamic-backends.html#overriding-the-default-admincontroller-in-practice), or adding a [custom event subscriber](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/complex-dynamic-backends.html#event-subscriber-example) to a Symfony event that monitors the Asset entity. Though I am not aware of how to accomplish this in relation to a category name change in EasyAdminBundle.